# Using JFileChooser only get part of txt. JAVA

Tags: java, file, text, bufferedreader, jfilechooser

i am using JFileChooser to get the text from a txt and later handle it.
But at the time i print it, the program only recover a part of the text, like a 20% of the end of the document. What's happenning?

Here's the code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;

public class Reader{

public static void main(String args[]){

    File inFile;
    FileReader fr;
    BufferedReader bufReader;
    JFileChooser chooser;

    int reply;
    String doc = "";

    String line;
try{

    chooser = new JFileChooser();
    reply = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
    doc = chooser.getCurrentDirectory().getPath() + System.getProperty("file.separator") +
            chooser.getSelectedFile().getName();
    inFile = new File(doc);
    fr = new FileReader(inFile);
    bufReader = new BufferedReader (fr);

    do{
        line = bufReader.readLine();
        if(line ==null )
            return;
        else{
                System.out.println(line);
        }
    } while(line!=null);

    bufReader.close();

}//end try
catch(Exception e)
{   System.out.println("error: "+e.getMessage());   }

}//main
}//end class reader
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with JFileChooser, absolutely nothing at all. Time to divide and conquer -- work on your file reading and output independent of JFileChooser and try to isolate your bug.

Comment: I have tried it and it works fine for me.  Is it only an issue with big files or with every file?

Comment: Also, why not simply get the selected file from the JFileChooser and not the Strings that you have to convert to file via a kludge?

Comment: It can be maybe a problem whit the file size? It can be so much big? As @Jens said..

Comment: @RicardoMoctezumaS Have you tried with a short file? Works with ist?

Comment: Are you using Windows?

Comment: Thank you everyone, im on mac, and the problem was only the console limit output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I run this class, a text file is completely printed. Could it be that you console buffer is simply not big enough, since you are using System.out to print the lines?

Comment: So, what can i do make the console bigger, or what can i use instead of System.out ?

Comment: That depends on what you are going to do with the data or what kind of console you are using. In Eclipse do it this way: Window -> Preferences -> type 'console' -> Run/Debug -> Console

Comment: That's was the problem, my console had a limit output, so i only "unchecked" the option of limit, and then it works fine! 
Thanks a lot!:3

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the wrong folder, try this:

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
File inFile = chooser.getSelectedFile()
FileReader fr = new FileReader(inFile);
BufferedReader bufReader = new BufferedReader (fr);
String line = bufReader.readLine();
while(line!=null){
  System.out.println(line);
  line = bufReader.readLine();
}
bufReader.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Such things may happen for a couple of reasons.

Normally when writing to a file and not closing it. Then still some data is not flushed to the file. (Not the case here.)

The console is also not totally synchrone, and might loose something if you suddenly exit the application, but every `System.out.println` flushes to the output.

However if you used `System.setOut(yourOut)` then again you are responsible for flushing/closing.

Finally, an error might have happened. Ensure you are not losing exceptions, like with an empty `catch (Exception e) { }`.

One error might be that the FileReader, that uses the default operating system encoding on MacOSX might try to read UTF-8 and hickup on some special characters. Not sure what then would happen.

The last error could be having the wrong directory, and a wrong version of the file.

```
 File inFile = chooser.getSelectedFile();
```

The above should be all that is needed.